# Visual Studio Team Services - build definition - fail on more warnings, or on less tests

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In TeamCity one can setup the build to fail on a metric change and on of the available metrics is number of warnings or number of tests, and more - I'm looking for similar functionality in Visual Studio Team Services.

Is it possible to fail a build if number of tests decreases or number of warnings increases?

---

EDIT: This is a first step in the direction for a long term goal to achieve TreatWarningsAsErrors (with few selected pragmas around obsolete code).

Comment: You could treat build warnings as errors per project or setup a build parameter. Unsure if there is anything for code coverage %age of unit tests failing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about number of tests but there is at least one build task in the marketplace that will let you fail a build if the code coverage falls below a certain level. Check out [Colin's ALM Corner Build and Release Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks).

While I don't know of a custom build task that watches the trend of passing/failing tests and let's you fail a build based on deltas, it's likely that one could be created.